# Doing a joined search in rails

Tags: join, search, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on doing a simple joined search within a rails project. What I want to do is find a description of an item based on what the user enters in a search box. The error that I'm most commonly getting is:

Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'item.description' in 'where clause': SELECT `item_instances`.* FROM `item_instances` INNER JOIN `items` ON `items`.`id` = `item_instances`.`item_id` WHERE `item`.`description` = 'server'

The search.html.erb page looks like the following:

```
<p>
  Search results base on database field <span class='bold'><%= @columnType %></span> 
  with value: <span class='bold'><%= @search_value %> </span>
</p>

<p>Total Report Cost: <span class='bold'>$<%= @cost %><span></p>

<table class='reportTable'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>Inv number</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>Description</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>Serial</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>PO number</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>PO date</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>Invoice</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>Date Out</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>Cost</th>
      <th class='reportTableHeaderCell'>Acro</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @item_instances.each do |item_instance| %>
      <tr class='searchTableRow'>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= link_to item_instance.inv_number, edit_item_instance_path(item_instance) %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.item.description %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.serial %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.po_number %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.po_date %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.invoice %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.date_out %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.cost %></td>
        <td class='reportTableCell'><%= item_instance.acro %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

item_instances.rb (model) file

```
class ItemInstance < ApplicationRecord
    validates :inv_number, :serial, :cost, presence: true
    belongs_to :item
    scope :in_order, ->{order(:description)}
    

    # Named Scopes 
    scope :search_for_records_by_date, ->(startDate, endDate) { where(date_out: startDate..endDate) }
    scope :search_for_records_by_column_and_value, ->(columnName, value) { where("#{columnName}": "#{value}") }
    
    #I know something may be wrong in here. 
    scope :search_for_records_by_column_and_value_item_table, ->(columnName, value) { where(item: "#{columnName}": "#{value}") }
    
end
```

The items model:

```
class Item < ApplicationRecord
    validates :description, :cost, :list_price, presence: true
    has_many :item_instances, dependent: :delete_all
    
    scope :in_order, ->{order(:description)}
    scope :search_for_active_items, ->(active) { where(active: active) }
    scope :search_for_records_by_column_and_value_on_items, ->(columnName, value) { where("#{columnName}": "#{value}") }
end
```

The item_instances Controller:

```
class ItemInstancesController < ApplicationController

    def search 
     # Getting the params from what the user submitted 
     @columnType = params[:columnType]
     @search_value = params[:search_value]


     if @columnType == 'description'
      # SIMPLE THINGS I've TRIED:
      # @item_instances = ItemInstance.joins(:item).where(item: {description: "server"})
      #@item_instances = ItemInstance.joins(:items)
      #I TRIED THIS JUST TO SEE IF I COULD GET ANYTHING
      @item_instances = ItemInstance.joins(:item).where(:item => {description: "server"})

      #@item_instances = ItemInstance.joins(:item).search_for_records_by_column_and_value_item_table(@columnType, @search_value)
    end

    respond_to do |format| 
      format.html { render :search }
    end

  end 

end
```

The Routes file:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :item_instances
  get '/report', to: 'item_instances#report'
  get '/search', to: 'item_instances#search'

  resources :items
  get '/active', to: 'items#active'

  # Route to the home page 
  root 'item_instances#home'

end
```

schema.rb File:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2020_08_17_190727) do

  create_table "item_instances", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer "inv_number"
    t.string "serial"
    t.integer "po_number"
    t.date "po_date"
    t.date "invoice"
    t.date "date_out"
    t.decimal "cost", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.string "acro"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.bigint "item_id"
    t.index ["item_id"], name: "fk_rails_6ea33fd9d0"
  end

  create_table "items", options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "description"
    t.decimal "cost", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.decimal "list_price", precision: 8, scale: 2
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.boolean "active"
  end

  add_foreign_key "item_instances", "items"
end
```

Please let me know if anything else is needed. I've looked through multiple articles and stackoverflow posts with no luck. Anything that can help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your item_instances_controller.rb, replace item with items in where condition. While where condition you must specify complete table name for comparison.

```
class ItemInstancesController < ApplicationController

    def search 

    #yourcode
      @item_instances = ItemInstance.joins(:item).where(:items => {description: "server"})

    #yourcode

  end 

end
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked and just want I needed! Have a great day and thank you for your help.